# PHP file is not reading my js script file

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I am trying to make sure my php file is reading my js file and when I click my decrease button, my console says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: decrease is not defined
onclick http://localhost:3000/index.php:1
```

I know this is indicating that my decrease() function does not exist when I click the button which is not true. I made sure that I included the html script tag as well.

Here are both of my files

**index.php**

```
  <?php
  $price = 3;
  $quantity = 5;
  $total = $price * $quantity
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Total: <?php echo $total; ?> </p>
    <button onclick='decrease();'>Click Me</button>
    <input type='text' id = 'num' value="0"></input>
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
let i = null;

 
  function decrease(){
    i = i - 1;
    document.getElementById('num').value = i;
    console.log(i)
  }
```

I've tried to restart my webserver a few times and it did not work. What am I missing that its preventing it from seeing the function in my external js script file?

Comment: Clear your **cache** and re-try

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I even restarted my browser completely.

Comment: (1) Did you try using another browser ? (say Firefox / Opera , etc ....)  (2) If in doubt, try this link : http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO14May2022.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding when working with a webserver, I do not use relative paths for my resources like js, CSS or images.

If your directory looks like this:

```
Main
 |- index.php
 |- index.js
```

Then you can import your javascript file like so without the dot `.`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/index.js'></script>
```

---

Sometimes when you create the project from Apache Netbean, the project URL will become `http://localhost/ProjectName`

For example, if you access your `index.php` from `http://localhost/ProjectName/index.php`, then you should be able to get the javascript file like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ProjectName/index.js'></script>
```

I have not tested it yet, hope it helps.

Comment: This sort of helped in regard to some sort of explanation, but it didn't clear up the issue even after I modified the path.

Comment: Are you able to view your javascript by opening `http://localhost/index.js` in the browser?

Comment: I just tried that and it reading my previous file. I need to clear the webserver's cache. I just cleared the browser cache

Comment: I was getting message that I overlooked saving that it failed to save my content of my js file. I had to tell it to overwrite it. and it works now.